# Locally Weighted Linear Regression

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, machine-learning

I am following the online [Stanford Course in Machine Learning](http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials.html) and I am trying to implement the algorithms on the fly in *Mathematica*.

Currently, I have issues with minimizing the Locally Weighted Linear Regression -- it hangs and just runs for more than 3 hours. I was hoping you might have some clues as to why.

The code I have is the following

```
trainX = {100, 320, 213, 512, 58, 84, 113, 142, 93, 121, 421, 432, 
   249, 254};
trainY = {140000, 400000, 241000, 489000, 78000, 123000, 139000, 
   143000, 97000, 134000, 392000, 458000, 311000, 378000};
trainComposed = 
  Transpose@{trainY, Table[1, {Length[trainX]}], trainX};
```

I define my hypothesis as

```
Hyp[x_, T_] := T.x;
```

and the cost function as

```
Cost[T_, case_, t_] := 
     1/2 Total[Exp[-(({##2} - case).({##2} - case)/(2t^2))]
               (Hyp[{##2}, T] - #1)^2 & @@@ trainComposed]
```

where `T` is a list of the parameters we are trying to find, `case` is the particular values on `x` for which we want to fit the model, and `t` is an arbitrary parameter that defines the weight of neighbouring data points.

I can calculate the cost without any issues, but when I try to minimise, it hangs. The code I use to run it with is

```
Clear[v]
T = Array[v, Length[trainComposed[[1]]] - 1];
Minimize[Cost[T, {1, 121}, 50], T]
```

I am essentially trying to minimise the following function

$$\sum_iw^{(i)}(y^{(i)}-\theta^Tx^{(i)})^2$$
where 
$$w^{(i)}=\exp\left(-\frac{(x^{(i)}-x)^2}{2\tau^2}\right)$$

and $y^{(i)}$ corresponds to the target value for the $y^{th}$ training example, $x^{(i)}$ is a feature vector of the $i^\text{th}$ example, and $x$ is the position vector for which we are currently doing the fit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `Minimize[]`? Do you really need symbolic results? If not, use `NMinimize[]` instead.

Comment: @J.M. This is essentially an answer. `NMinimize` gives immediate results.

Comment: @J.M. it works, thanks. Can you please submit an answer? Moreover, I'd be happy if you could elaborate a bit on why Minimize wouldn't work in this example; I have used it earlier without any issues to a similar problem, and thus I didn't think of this distinction. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In part, your trouble stemmed from an attempt to determine exact/symbolic results from your data. Even for this modestly-sized set, the objective function you were feeding to `Minimize[]` is already sufficiently complicated, which is why it takes long.

As I previously noted, using `NMinimize[]` instead will give you the numerical values you need. Less expensively, tho, one can use the built-in functions specialized for the purpose. For instance, you can use `LeastSquares[]` like so:

```
With[{case = {1, 121}, t = 50}, 
     wd = DiagonalMatrix[Exp[-Map[Composition[#.# &, {1, #} - case &], trainX]/(4 t^2)]]; 
     LeastSquares[wd.DesignMatrix[Transpose[{trainX, trainY}], x, x], wd.(N @ trainY)]]
```

The sufficiently observant reader will notice two features in this *weighted least squares* problem: 1. the diagonal matrix contains the *square roots* of the original weights (think about why this must be so); and 2. we need to use `N[]` in this case as well (without it, we end up doing the same thing that doomed the `Minimize[]` approach).

Of course, since weighted regression is a relatively common operation, *Mathematica* provides for a function called, appropriately enough, `LinearModelFit[]`. Here's how to use it for your problem:

```
With[{case = {1, 121}, t = 50}, 
     LinearModelFit[Transpose[{trainX, trainY}], x, x, 
                    Weights -> Exp[-Map[Composition[#.# &, {1, #} - case &],
                                        trainX]/(2 t^2)]] @ "BestFitParameters"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a follow-up to @J.M.'s answer to show the effect of the value of `t`:

```
trainX = {100, 320, 213, 512, 58, 84, 113, 142, 93, 121, 421, 432, 249, 254};
trainY = {140000, 400000, 241000, 489000, 78000, 123000, 139000, 
   143000, 97000, 134000, 392000, 458000, 311000, 378000};
rX = MinMax[trainX];
rY = MinMax[trainY];

Manipulate[

 (* Make a table of predictions across the range of the predictor variable *)
 predicted = Table[LinearModelFit[Transpose[{trainX, trainY}], x, x,
     Weights -> Exp[-Map[Composition[#.# &, {1, #} - {1, z} &], trainX]/(2 t^2)]]@z,
   {z, rX[[1]], rX[[2]], (rX[[2]] - rX[[1]])/100}];

 (* Plot results *)
 ListPlot[{
   Transpose[{trainX, trainY}],
   Transpose[{Range[rX[[1]], rX[[2]], (rX[[2]] - rX[[1]])/100], 
     predicted}]},
  PlotRange -> {rX, rY}, Joined -> {False, True}],

 {{t, 50}, 5, 300, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}]
```

[image: Data and fit]
[image: Data and fit with different tuning parameter]

Comment: Nice!$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 3):

Another follow up, specifically to @Jim Baldwin's comment. Instead of plotting the full curve, we can also plot a certain number of points and see how they vary with the parameter t, i.e.:

```
Clear[v]
th = Array[v, Length[trainComposed[[1]]] - 1];
lwrPlot = 
 Manipulate[
  Show[listPlot, 
   With[{x = #}, 
      With[{bounds = 
         Values@NMinimize[
           Cost[th, {1, x}, 
             t], th][[2]]}, {Plot[
         Hyp[{1, y}, bounds], {y, x - span, x + span}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thin}], 
        ListPlot[{{x, Hyp[{1, x}, bounds]}}, 
         PlotStyle -> Orange]}]] & /@ 
    Range[Min[trainX], Max[trainX], (Max[trainX] - Min[trainX])/(
     points - 1)]], {{t, 20}, 5, 80, 5}, {{span, 40}, 10, 200, 
   10}, {{points, 5}, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image: Example of executed code]